# Adding a parameters to URL limitation

Tags: php, android, ios, sql

I am working on an mobile application which allows user to post product to the server. I am getting user `user id, zip, product info, price, condition` and `images`. I could able to get the information of zip, price and condition by the following format and it works.

```
http://www.myproduct.com/products.php?user_id=10311&zip=77072&price=$13&condition=3
```

However it allows only 1024 characters. Therefore I am stuck how to send product info and images in that format. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not send them using `POST` method?

Comment: Could you please illustrate by giving an example of useful resources link?

Answer (score 1):

That's what I was searching today.

This might help you.

**On a side note : POST method is a better way.**

Try using hidden element to pass data between different pages.

Refer:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-variables.html

Answer (score 1):

URL parameters are normally used to do gets instead of POST. Try using POST and put the name value pairs you wish to post into the body of the request. The body is not limited to the 1024 like the URL string is. Depending on the back end service the body can be an HTML form, and XML string, or JSON.